# Wordpress TinyMCE "Add media" button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

In some situations when I'm browsing Wordpress (4.7.2) admin area in Firefox (51.0.1) TinyMCE "Add media" button won't working. Furthermore opening Mozilla Dev Tools in console tab there are some JS errors.

```
TypeError: d(...) is null[Learn More]  mediaelement-and-player.min.js:15:6254
mejs.MediaFeatures.init/c.supportsPointerEvents< http://localhost/WP/theme/wp-includes/js/mediaelement/mediaelement-and-player.min.js:15:6254
mejs.MediaFeatures.init http://localhost/WP/theme/wp-includes/js/mediaelement/mediaelement-and-player.min.js:15:6035
<anonymous> http://localhost/WP/theme/wp-includes/js/mediaelement/mediaelement-and-player.min.js:15:7968

TypeError: $(...).not(...).filter(...).mediaelementplayer is not a function[Learn More]  wp-mediaelement.js:44:4
initialize http://localhost/WP/theme/wp-includes/js/mediaelement/wp-mediaelement.js:44:4
n.Callbacks/i http://localhost/WP/theme/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js:2:27444
n.Callbacks/j.fireWith http://localhost/WP/theme/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js:2:28213
.ready http://localhost/WP/theme/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js:2:30004
K http://localhost/WP/theme/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js:2:30366
```

What I'm seeing is that problem is with media element plugin WordPress is using. I searched the web to see if there is a similar problem about this, but couldn't find anything. Anyone have clue what is going on? Just to mention that there is no problem in Chrome with this.

Comment: Can you make sure that jQuery is specified before the media plugin in your WP install? Just check the source code and see the order of the scripts. Also, does this happen in Chrome too?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is not happening in Chrome

Comment: Can you check the Console in Chrome? No errors at all?